# Migrate all MySQL queries to Postgres in Codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter-3

We have a PHP project using Codeigniter framework(v3). The project is using MySQL database hosted on AWS RDS instance.

We are planning to migrate the database to Postgres. The problem is quotes. The existing project is using single quotes outside the query string.
For eg.,

```
$query = $this->db->select('o.*,concat("O",o.id) as id, c.name as customer,w.name as warehouse,a.name as account,a.type as channel,
         IFNULL(oi.qty,0) as qty, IFNULL(oi.picked_qty,0) as picked_qty, IFNULL(oi.boxes,0) as boxes,IFNULL(oi.packed_qty,0) as packed_qty,
         IFNULL(oi.shipped_qty,0) as shipped_qty', FALSE)
                ->join('customers c', 'c.id=o.customer_id')
                ->join('warehouses w', 'w.id=o.warehouse_id')
                ->join('accounts a', 'a.id=o.account_id')
                ->join('(select order_id, sum(qty) as qty,  sum(boxes) as boxes,sum(picked_qty) as picked_qty, sum(packed_qty) as packed_qty,
         sum(shipped_qty) as shipped_qty,  group_concat(IFNULL(order_items.sku,"null") separator "|") as skus,
           group_concat(order_items.in_stock separator "|") as in_stock, group_concat(distinct(order_items.upc) separator "|") as upcs,
           group_concat(distinct(order_items.ean) separator "|") as eans , group_concat(brand_name) brands,  group_concat(product_category) categories 
            from order_items  left join upc on order_items.sku = upc.sku group by order_items.order_id) oi', 'oi.order_id=o.id', 'left')
                ->from('orders o');
```

The working Postgres version is:

```
$query = $this->db->select("o.*,concat('O',o.id) as id, c.name as customer,w.name as warehouse,a.name as account,a.type as channel,
         coalesce(oi.qty,0) as qty, coalesce(oi.picked_qty,0) as picked_qty, coalesce(oi.boxes,0) as boxes,coalesce(oi.packed_qty,0) as packed_qty,
         coalesce(oi.shipped_qty,0) as shipped_qty", FALSE)
                ->join("customers c", "c.id=o.customer_id")
                ->join("warehouses w", "w.id=o.warehouse_id")
                ->join("accounts a", "a.id=o.account_id")
                ->join("(select order_id, sum(qty) as qty,  sum(boxes) as boxes,sum(picked_qty) as picked_qty, sum(packed_qty) as packed_qty,
         sum(shipped_qty) as shipped_qty,  string_agg(coalesce(order_items.sku,'null'), '|') as skus,
         string_agg(order_items.in_stock, '|') as in_stock, string_agg(distinct(order_items.upc), '|') as upcs,
         string_agg(distinct order_items.ean, '|') as eans , string_agg(brand_name, '') brands,  string_agg(product_category, '') categories 
            from order_items  left join upc on order_items.sku = upc.sku group by order_items.order_id) oi", 'oi.order_id=o.id', 'left')
                ->from("orders o");
```

Notice the difference in single and double quotes in the above queries. Codeigniter expects query string inside double quotes when working with Postgres, we can not wrap a query using single quotes and use double quotes inside it,for eg concat('O',o.id) is correct while concat("O",o.id) is not correct using Codeigniter active record

We have hundreds of these queries in the project using several Codeigniter's active record functions like this->db->query, this->db->select, and it's a nightmare converting them all manually, I tried writing a script for it but its not much useful either because of php variables embedded inside queries like '.$cond.'

Is there something that can help to migrate all these queries quickly?
Note - We are using 'postgre' databse driver in database.php file for migrating to Postgres

Comment: This isn't quite right: "Postgres expects query string inside double quotes". PostgreSQL wants string literals in SQL to use single quotes, it doesn't know or care what you're using to quote PHP's strings. PostgreSQL doesn't care about the quotes in `join("customers c", "c.id=o.customer_id")`, just the ones in `concat('O',o.id)` and similar bits of SQL.

Comment: I wrote it wrong, I meant "Codeigniter expects query string inside double quotes, ,when using postgres" concat('O',o.id) works while concat("O",o.id) doesn't, we need to wrap the queries in double quotes when using Codeigniter with postgres